# Is there a way to force Solr to read the indexes every X minutes?

Tags: solr

I am trying to use Solr to read and search trough the indexes provided by an another application. These indexes are copied to a NAS every 15 minutes.

Is there a way to force Solr to re-read the indexes every 15 minutes ? Is there a way to set a searcher to expire or to be reloaded using maybe a CRON expression?

I am aware that I can reload the core... but I'm asking if maybe is there an another way...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to write some CRON expression it could be done in that way:

Solr have an endpoint for reloading a core, so all you need is to hit this URI every X minutes.

> Load a new core from the same configuration as an existing registered
>   core. While the "new" core is initalizing, the "old" one will continue
>   to accept requests. Once it has finished, all new request will go to
>   the "new" core, and the "old" core will be unloaded.
>
> http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a CRON expression.

[DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) will allow you to update your Solr index based on your NAS-indexes.
Look for the "delta-import" command "for incremental imports and change detection":

```
 http://<host>:<port>/solr/<collection_name>/dataimport?command=delta-import
```

Programmatically using a [Client API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Introduction+to+Client+APIs) like SolrJ:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_name>");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("command", "delta-import");
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
request.setPath("/dataimport");
server.request(request);
```